# How to get the Rating of image files from Exif library

Tags: c#, exif

I am using [EXIFextractor-library-to-extract-EXIF-information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11305/EXIFextractor-library-to-extract-EXIF-information).It works fine but my problem is that i want to extract Image rating means (star rating) but in that Exif i don't find any property with `Rating` or `Star` name so getting problem that how to get the star rating of Images.

I am using a property to find a rating and sometimes it works fine but many time it's showing me a wrong value.The property is

```
string rate = ((System.Drawing.Image)((er).bmp)).PropertyItems[1].Value[0].ToString();
```

So please tell me that how we can achieve `Rating` value of images.

*Example:-*

[image]

This image is having rating of 3 stars so how to get that value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i solve my problem.The propertyId for Find Image Rating is `18246`
i Just replace my code like

```
PropertyItem propItem = er.bmp.GetPropertyItem(18246);
String rating = BitConverter.ToInt16(propItem.Value, 0).ToString();
```

It works fine for me.